# How to send data to an already open website

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm a total noob to website development and I'm trying to send data by a HTTP POST to an already opened website, let me explain:

I have a website, that it's being called from another website (that I'm not developing) into a new window, my website performs a query and gets the data that has to be sent back. I need to know if my website can send the data to the already open website that called mine, or do I have to send the data to a new window. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't a way to send data to an open web page unless you've specifically designed the system to accept messages from the server. Normally web pages poll the server, asking for information back.

If you really need to push data to a page [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) can do this very successfully, but the settup can be daunting and there's alot of work required to wire up the server and web page so they can talk.

Comment: ape sounds great! unfortunately, I don't have the time to do this. Thanks.